# Dijkstra's Algorithm termination

Tags: algorithm, graph-algorithm

Something must be wrong in my understanding of the algorithm. How is it supposed to work on the following graph.

As I understand it, if the starting vertex is (5) then the algorithm would go, 5->4->1 and then terminate. Vertex (2) would still have infinity as it's weight.

from wikipedia:
if the smallest tentative distance among the nodes in the unvisited set is infinity (when planning a complete traversal), then stop. The algorithm has finished.

[image: Graph]

Comment: I think my confusion was in the Queue. I was thinking that the Queue only contains vertices reachable from the current vertex. So, when I got to the (1) Vertex then Queue was empty.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it would investigate `3 -> 2` after it's done with the `4 -> 1` branch. All children of the currently investigated node are added to the queue, and then from the queue the node with the smallest tentative distance is taken to be processed next.